# Ask Bibtex not to abbreviate

Tags: bibtex, citing, apa-style

This is my bibtex entry:

```
@online{godt2023transplantsum,
    author = {WHO, World Health Organization and ONT, Organización Nacional de Trasplantes},
    title = {{Global observatory on donation and transplantation}},
    year = {2023},
    url = {http://www.transplant-observatory.org},
    note = {Accessed on 2023-09-13},
    organization = {Global Observatory on Donation and Transplantation},
}
```

I want to keep the [WHO and ONT, 2023] when I do `\cite{godt2023transplantsum}`. However I want that reference to say "WHO, World Health Organization and ONT, Organización Nacional de Trasplantes (2023) Global .... Accessed on ..." instead of "WHO, W. H. O. and ONT, O. N. d. T. (2023) Global .... Accessed on ..."

This (see below) fixes it, but I don't have [WHO and ONT, 2023] anymore but a super long [WHO, World Health Organization and ... (2023)] reference.

```
@online{godt2023transplantsum,
    author = {{WHO, World Health Organization} and {ONT, Organización Nacional de Trasplantes}},
    title = {{Global observatory on donation and transplantation}},
    year = {2023},
    url = {http://www.transplant-observatory.org},
    note = {Accessed on 2023-09-13},
    organization = {Global Observatory on Donation and Transplantation},
}
```

How can I have the abbreviation in the reference section but not when I cite it? I have to sacrifice either the reference section or when I cite.

**Complete MRE:**

Main .tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}

\title{Sample Document}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
The significant impact of global observatories on donation and transplantation is well documented \cite{godt2023transplantsum}.

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

references.bib

```py
@online{godt2023transplantsum,
    author = "WHO, World Health Organization and ONT, Organización Nacional de Trasplantes",
    title = "{Global observatory on donation and transplantation}",
    year = "2023",
    url = "http://www.transplant-observatory.org",
    note = "Accessed on 2023-09-13",
    organization = "Global Observatory on Donation and Transplantation",
}
```

Comment: Do you use a citation management package such as `natbib`? Please advise. Please also tell us which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: No I am not. I added a complete MRE in my post to be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you employ the [natbib](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/) citation management package, as it has a mechanism for creating "alias"-type citation call-outs. Happily, the `natbib` package is fully compatible with the  `apalike` bibliography style. The following code provides two utility macros, `\citepa` and `\citeta`, that act like natbib's usual `\citet` and `\citep` macros, except that they print out the aliased authors.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@online{godt2023transplantsum,
    author = {{World Health Organization (WHO)} and 
              {Organización Nacional de Trasplantes (WHO)}},
    title  = {Global observatory on donation and transplantation},
    year   = {2023},
    url    = {http://www.transplant-observatory.org},
    note   = {Accessed on 2023-09-13},
    organization = {Global Observatory on Donation and Transplantation},
}
\end{filecontents}

%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[authoryear,square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
% create two utility macros:
\newcommand{\citeta}[1]{\citetalias{#1} [\citeyear{#1}]}
\newcommand{\citepa}[1]{[\citetalias{#1}, \citeyear{#1}]}

% One '\defcitealias' command per aliased entry
\defcitealias{godt2023transplantsum}{WHO and ONT}

\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\noindent
\citepa{godt2023transplantsum},
\citeta{godt2023transplantsum}.
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```